# Alter column datatype in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `dbo.ExceptionMessage` and now I want to change the column datatype from `nvarchar(100)` to `nvarchar(250)`.

I used an `alter` query for changing this

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.ExceptionMessage 
    ALTER COLUMN Address NVARCHAR(250)
```

and when executing this query, I get this error:

> The object 'AddressView' is dependent on column 'Address'.
>   `ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Address` failed because one or more objects access this column.

I have a view named `AdressView` in my database, I am using this address column in this `AddressView` .

Please help

Comment: You shuld remove all references to your field, before alter column, and re-add after

Comment: How to remove the reference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your AddressView definition must have a "WITH SCHEMABINDING" --

```
CREATE VIEW AddressView
    WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
-- SELECT STATEMENTS
GO
```

You can remove this clause in your ALTER VIEW statment --

```
ALTER VIEW AddressView 
-- WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
-- SELECT STATEMENTS
GO
```

After altering the base tables ideally you should put the "WITH SCHEMABINDING" again in the view. Because it will prevent from altering the base tables accidently. This should help you solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

// If you are having any constraint with that table then first drop that

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo.ExceptionMessage] 
    DROP CONSTRAINT [CONSTRAINT_NAME];

ALTER TABLE dbo.ExceptionMessage 
    ALTER COLUMN Address NVARCHAR(250)

ALTER TABLE [dbo.ExceptionMessage] 
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (CONSTRAINT_NAME) 
        REFERENCES REFERENCE_TABLE_NAME(REFERENCE_COLUMN_NAME);
```

Comment: The last command needs to be `ADD **CONSTRAINT** (constraint_name) FOREIGN KEY (column name) REFERENCES......`